# Error middleware is not reaching with next() function

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

So, when I call `next(errorObj)`, it's not coming to the error handler. I am using express.

**app.ts**

```js
// ... routes
// Route middleware
app.use('/auth', authRouter)

// Error middleware
app.use(errorHandler)
```

**controllers/authController.ts**

```js
export const register = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction,
) => {
  try {
    throw new Error(
      `Email or username is already exists. Please try again with different one.`,
    )
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

**middleware/errorHandler.ts**

```js
const errorHandler = (error: Error, req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode || 500
  const responseBody: ErrorResponse = {
    status: statusCode,
    message: error.message || 'Internal Server Error',
  }

  res.status(statusCode).json(responseBody)
}

export default errorHandler
```

I was expecting to get the JSON response with `status` and `message` when there's an error. But I am getting the default response.

This is the response I am getting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Error: Email or username is already exists. Please try again with different one.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at register (/Users/musab/Documents/Projects/winner-vpn/backend/src/controllers/authController.ts:21:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please find the https://stackblitz.com/edit/76293442-error-middleware code which is working here.

Comment: your `errorHandler` middleware function needs `next` argument (four arguments). `const errorHandler = (error: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/76293442-error-middleware

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: (err, req, res, next).

~ [Error Handling - Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Adding next as the 4th parameter in the error handler should fix the issue.

```
const errorHandler = (error: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
```